# EE2.5.2 login doesn't work from Safari 7.1

Tags: ee2, login

A client on EE2.5.2 has just found that they can't login with Safari 7.1 on OSX. Chrome and FF work fine, but in Safari, pressing Submit just returns them to the blank login page. I tried changing "Control Panel Session Type" to "Cookies only" but that didn't do it.

I could try upgrading them to 2.9 but don't want to charge them for an upgrade if it's not guaranteed to fix the issue.

Any ideas why this might be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The 2.5.x branch has cache issues if I recall and depending on your system, 2.9.x can break a few things (plugins, conditionals, etc). Upgrading to a stable version before all the big changes, like 2.7.3, should be enough to enable "cookies only" and have it work reliably.

Comment: Interested to see if this works - (if so, please mark the answer as correct for those who follow along).

Comment: I've just emailed my client to see if they're willing to pay for the upgrade – if they do I'll report back!